# How to go from $u^{2/3}-5u^{1/3}+7=0$ to $u^2-20u+343=0$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have absolutely no clue how to do this - any hints would be appreciated.

So far, I have tried multiplying each term by a power of u, but this leads nowhere...

Comment: Also, can someone please modify the title please - the formatting is quite tricky

Comment: Is that a power or factor on the second $u$?  (the $1/3$)

Comment: You can use my edit to learn a bit of MathJax - see the source code by clicking "edit".

Comment: The title should probably read $u^{\color{#C00}{2}}-20u+343$

Comment: I have changed the second equation to $u^2-20u+343$ in the title, since that is the question the OP presumably intended to ask and which most people have answered.

Comment: @robjohn Right, so I guess that's a typo in my mark scheme... Thank you for spotting that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution inspired by the mechanical process to calculate a Groebner basis of the ideal $\langle x^2 - 5x + 7, x^3 - u \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x, u]$.

Let $x := u^{1/3}$; then we have the system of equations
$$x^2 - 5x + 7 = 0, \quad (1) \\ x^3 - u = 0. \quad (2)$$
Now, let us try to eliminate $x$.  By taking $x (1) - (2)$, we get:
$$-5x^2 + 7x + u = 0. \quad (3)$$
Similarly, $5(1) + (3)$ now gives:
$$-18x + 35 + u = 0. \quad (4)$$
Now, from here we can get $x = \frac{1}{18} (u + 35)$; then substituting into (1) will give a quadratic polynomial equation in terms of $u$.  Using a CAS, I get that the substitution gives $\frac{1}{324} (u^2 - 20u + 343) = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Cube both sides of $u^{2/3}=5u^{1/3}-7$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
u^2
&=125u\overbrace{-525u^{2/3}+735u^{1/3}}^{-105u}-343\\
&=20u-343
\end{align}
$$
where $-105u=-105\overbrace{\left(5u^{1/3}-7\right)}^{u^{2/3}}u^{1/3}$

Therefore,
$$
u^2-20u+343=0
$$

---

**In General**

Suppose we had $u^{2/3}=au^{1/3}+b$, then
$$
\begin{align}
u
&=au^{2/3}+bu^{1/3}\\
&=a\left(au^{1/3}+b\right)+bu^{1/3}\\
&=\color{#C00}{\left(a^2+b\right)u^{1/3}+ab}\\
u^2
&=\left(a^2+b\right)^2u^{2/3}+2ab\left(a^2+b\right)u^{1/3}+(ab)^2\\
&=\left(a^2+b\right)^2\left(au^{1/3}+b\right)+2ab\left(a^2+b\right)u^{1/3}+(ab)^2\\
&=\color{#C00}{\left(a^2+b\right)\left(a^3+3ab\right)u^{1/3}+b\left(a^4+3a^2b+b^2\right)}
\end{align}
$$
Then, we can combine the two red formulas to get
$$
u^2=\left(a^3+3ab\right)u+b^3
$$

---

**Complex Approach**

Let $v=u^{1/3}$ and $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$. Then note that
$$
\left(v^2-av-b\right)\left(v^2\omega^2-av\omega-b\right)\left(v^2\omega-av\omega^2-b\right)=v^6-\left(a^3+3ab\right)v^3-b^3
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write $t=u^{1/3}$ so $t^2-5t+7=0$. Plug now $u=t^3$ in

$$f(u) = u^3-20u+343 = t^9-20t^3+343 = ... $$ You must get $f(u)=0$. Don't forget to use $t^2 = 5t-7$

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%5E(2%2F3)+-+5u%5E(1%2F3)+%2B+7+%3D+0
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%C2%B3+-+20u+%2B+343+%3D+0

The solutions of both equations are not the same. Hence there is no rewriting the one into the other.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$(-7)^3=(u^{2/3}-5u^{1/3})^3=u^2-125u-15u(-7)$$